# Get parameter from ajax to controller Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to pass value of id to controller in Laravel

my Ajax Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


            $(document).on('click', '.brnch_clk', function () {
                //alert('ok')
                var branchid = $(this).data('branch');
                $('#txt_branchid').val(branchid);
                alert($(this).data('branch'));

                $.ajax({
                    'url': 'search',
                    'type': 'GET',
                    'data': {id: branchid},

                    success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                        if(data == "success")
                            alert(response);
                    },
                    error: function(response){
                        alert('Error'+response);
                    }



                });
            });

        });
```

My Controller:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $member = $request->get('id');
    return json_encode($member);
}
```

My Route:

```
Route::get('search', 'ShowstaffController@search');
```

My Link:

```
<a href="{{URL('search')}}" class="brnch_clk"
    data-branch="{{$value->branch_id}}"> {{$value->Branch_Name}}
</a>
```

How can i get parametter id from ajax to controller??

Comment: I suppose `$member = $request->get('id');` does not work.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai yes i get blank result how can i get a real result?

Comment: try this : `$request->query('id');`

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai result still blank

Comment: Try using : `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai : Error Undefined index: id

Answer (score 3):

You can not send `GET` value in `data`. Send it in the `URL` as a query string.
Check this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        $(document).on('click', '.brnch_clk', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //alert('ok')
            var branchid = $(this).data('branch');
            $('#txt_branchid').val(branchid);
            //alert($(this).data('branch'));

            $.ajax({
                'url': 'search?id='+branchid,
                'type': 'GET',
                'data': {},

                success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                    if(data == "success")
                        alert(response);
                },
                error: function(response){
                    alert('Error'+response);
                }



            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: still get blank result

Comment: Result still blank

Comment: When i change url like yours should i update my route and link with parameter id??

Comment: nop, open `Network` tab on your browser, and check `request` data. Can you see the `id` when you click `.brnch_clk` ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `'url': 'search?id='+branchid` in place of `'url': 'search'` should force JQuery to send `data` as GET parameters. Otherwise, data is sent as POST parameters.

Comment: still can't get the result because still out put blank

Comment: Pass in parameter via route. `Route::get('search/{id}', 'ShowstaffController@search');` and `public function search($id)`

Answer (score 0):

You should **get** the parameter from `query string` using `query` method.

```
$request->query('id');
```

Comment: still get blank result

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, I used all solutions, but could not get the result.

Here what I did,

- Created a **formData** object
- append the **param id**
- passed **form object** to ajax **data attribute**
- retrieve the value in **laravel controller** using **$request->get('id')**;

Here jQuery Snippet

```
 var branchid = $(this).data('branch');
 var form = new formData();
 form.append('id',branchid)
                $.ajax({
                    'url': 'search',
                    'type': 'GET',
                    'data': form,

                    success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                        if(data == "success")
                            alert(response);
                    },
                    error: function(response){
                        alert('Error'+response);
                    }
                });
```

Laravel Controller

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
 $id = $request->get('id');
}
```

**NOTE:** You don't need to encode json, Laravel by default send response in JSON format.